# Why MSI doesn't expand [CommonAppDataFolder] variable?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Visual Studio 2015, WIX, MSI-installer.

At first I get the target platform. This code is inside of my `UI` xml-element:

```
<!-- Define platform-specific names and locations -->
<?if $(var.Platform) = x64 ?>
<?define PLATFORMPROGRAMFILESFOLDER = "ProgramFiles64Folder" ?>
<?else ?>
<?define PLATFORMPROGRAMFILESFOLDER = "ProgramFilesFolder" ?>
<?endif ?>
```

Yes, I do it through the preprocessor, but it works without any problem because I build my MSI-installer for x86 and x64 separately. I don't know how to do the same in runtime. *I would be very grateful if someone showed me how to do it*, but my current question is about other... I have a problem...

It works:

```
...
<!-- I am forced to define the INSTALLFOLDER again (inside of 'UI') because 
SelectInstallDirectory dialog doesnt see this property. -->
<Property Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="$(env.ProgramData)\Autodesk\ApplicationPlugins\ProxyTools.bundle\"/>
...
<RadioButtonGroup Property="INSTALLFOLDER">
  <RadioButton
    Text="[$(var.PLATFORMPROGRAMFILESFOLDER)]Autodesk\ApplicationPlugins\ProxyTools.bundle\"
    Value="[$(var.PLATFORMPROGRAMFILESFOLDER)]Autodesk\ApplicationPlugins\ProxyTools.bundle\"
    Height="13" Width="500" X="5" Y="5"/>
  <RadioButton
    Text="$(env.ProgramData)\Autodesk\ApplicationPlugins\ProxyTools.bundle\"
    Value="$(env.ProgramData)\Autodesk\ApplicationPlugins\ProxyTools.bundle\"
    Height="13" Width="500" X="5" Y="20"/>
  <RadioButton
    Text="[AppDataFolder]Autodesk\ApplicationPlugins\ProxyTools.bundle\"
    Value="[AppDataFolder]Autodesk\ApplicationPlugins\ProxyTools.bundle\"
    Height="13" Width="500" X="5" Y="35"/>
</RadioButtonGroup>
...
```

It creates the dialog:

[image]

Pay attention that I haven't any problem with `[AppDataFolder]` using...

But `$(env.ProgramData)` is evaluated *by preprocessor*. Therefore I am to replace each `$(env.ProgramData)\` substring to `[CommonAppDataFolder]` for the value evaluating in runtime:

```
...
<!-- I am forced to define the INSTALLFOLDER again (inside of 'UI') because 
SelectInstallDirectory dialog doesnt see this property. -->
<Property Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="[CommonAppDataFolder]Autodesk\ApplicationPlugins\ProxyTools.bundle\"/>
...
<RadioButtonGroup Property="INSTALLFOLDER">
  <RadioButton
    Text="[$(var.PLATFORMPROGRAMFILESFOLDER)]Autodesk\ApplicationPlugins\ProxyTools.bundle\"
    Value="[$(var.PLATFORMPROGRAMFILESFOLDER)]Autodesk\ApplicationPlugins\ProxyTools.bundle\"
    Height="13" Width="500" X="5" Y="5"/>
  <RadioButton
    Text="[CommonAppDataFolder]Autodesk\ApplicationPlugins\ProxyTools.bundle\"
    Value="[CommonAppDataFolder]Autodesk\ApplicationPlugins\ProxyTools.bundle\"
    Height="13" Width="500" X="5" Y="20"/>
  <RadioButton
    Text="[AppDataFolder]Autodesk\ApplicationPlugins\ProxyTools.bundle\"
    Value="[AppDataFolder]Autodesk\ApplicationPlugins\ProxyTools.bundle\"
    Height="13" Width="500" X="5" Y="35"/>
</RadioButtonGroup>
...
```

But at this case I get errorr when I launch my MSI, because `[CommonAppDataFolder]` wasn't expanded:

[image]

Why does it happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I should have thought of and mentioned this while answering your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39998321). What matters here is now context. The two attributes in question are the Text and Value attribute on the RadioButton element. These correspond to the columns of the same name in the [RadioButton table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370962.aspx). I was about to say that Text is [Formatted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368609.aspx), and Value is not. But they both are Formatted.

So I can't quite justify the behavior; it looks like it should work.

But it's easy to work around. Instead of using values that match your text, use short values like `"ProgramFiles"`, `"ProgramData"`, and `"AppData"`. Then elsewhere, possibly on the Next button of that dialog, add SetProperty or SetDirectory custom actions that set `INSTALLFOLDER` to the values previously stored in the Value attribute, each conditioned on the value of `INSTALLFOLDER` matching the short alternate value. These custom actions will definitely expand the property references.

Take it one step further by separating the RadioButtonGroup property from the directory property (only use `INSTALLFOLDER` for one of them), and then things will display correctly if you click Back and revisit the page.

Comment: I have tried to use `[%environmentvariable]` format: `[%ProgramData]` for the `%ProgramData%` environment variable using instead of `[CommonAppDataFolder]`, but it doesn't work in my project.

Comment: The `[ProgramData]` doesn't work too. A get the runtime error for both cases: MSI can't expand these names.

Comment: I don't understand why I have this problem for `[CommonAppDataFolder]` but at the same time I haven't problem for `[AppDataFolder]`...

Comment: Also I have tried the `%ProgramData%` but it doesn't work still in my MSI.

Comment: Did you put any of these in a SetProperty or SetDirectory custom action, like my answer describes, or did you try them in the RadioButton/@Value attribute? (Not relevant here, but for an environment variable reference, use `[%name]` in MSI.)

Comment: I placed them in the RadioButton/@Value attribute. I am not expert in WIX, and I don't know how to do the SetProperty or SetDirectory custom action still... :( I will search info about it in Internet, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you referenced CommonAppDataFolder anywhere in your directory references? How about AppDataFolder? Are they both in the Directory table of your MSI file? It's possible that Windows Installer will evaluate only the directories that are explicitly named in your Directory table, not every possible folder property that you're not even going to use.

Also, are your dialogs after CostInitialize and CostFinalize? Check the MSI directly to be sure.